# How to increse the number of undo steps stored by emacs?

Tags: undo

Looking into undo, there are variables: `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit`, `undo-outer-limit`.

While I can blindly set these to a big number and hope for the best.
Whats a good rule of thumb for setting these values that matches it to an *approximate* memory usage?

Comment: You missed `undo-limit`. Since [a single step can take an arbitrary amount memory](https://debbugs.gnu.org/31104), it seems difficult to come up with a conversion factor...

Comment: Corrected, thanks for the link.